# Changing the style of leftmost menu item

Tags: html, css

Here is my Codepen demo which I want to show like image snap below the link:

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/qklCy)

Snap:

[image]

I used this css:

```
.menu > ul > li:first-child {
      color: red !important;
}
```

To make left most link `Red` but still it shows `Grey` line.

Actually it should look like this:

[image]

Problem 2:

The length of the line above alert box should span to entire width of the page. How to do this?

I tried with chaging:

```
.menu > ul {    
    display: block;    
    list-style: none;    
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #9e9e9e;
    width: 152%;  // makig it 200% increase width of entire page. Rather I want to increase the width of lie only
    margin-left: -2%;

}
```

Comment: clear your second problem i cant understand

Comment: @SridharR: that is about horizotal line above the alert message `Article changes everyday ...`. I want legth of that line = width of the page. Settig it 100% does not solve problem

Comment: because it is inside col-md-6 so height based on a parent div.if you want to change set fixed height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.menu > ul > li:first-child a {

  color: red !important;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/idktK)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, the only issue is that the `a` is getting overrid by the color from actual properties for the hyperlink as

```
a {
  // properties..
}
```

Change the code to this:

```
.menu > ul > li:first-child a {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Which will apply the settings to the hyperlink of the left most list item under the un ordered list in the element with class menu! :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add anchor selector at the end of:

```
.menu > ul > li:first-child a {
   color: red !important;
}
```